# Traffic shaping linux upload issue

Tags: linux, upload, traffic

Im currently working on a traffic shaping in linux. We have a client connected to a server running nat and dhcp. What we want to do is limit both the upload and download speed of the client/clients.

However only download limit works.

Download limit(Part of the script) WORKING

```
tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:1 classid 1:4 htb rate 30000kbit
tc filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst 192.168.0.101/32 flowid 1:4
```

Upload limit(Part of the script)

```
tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:1 classid 1:4 htb rate 30000kbit
tc filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip src 192.168.0.101/32 flowid 1:4
```

The only thing that is changed in the upload part is "dst" to "src" Problem is when we replace the download part of the script with the upload part, no limiting is done.? what is wrong

Edited after David Schwartz answered me:

My qdisc that i used both upload and download limiting on.

```
tc qdisc add dev eth1 root handle 1: htb default 30
```

Qdisc i am adding now

```
tc qdisc add dev eth1 ingress
```

Answer (score 2):

If the download limit is working, it must be connected to the egress qdisc, since it's an egress rule. If you attach the upload script to the same qdisc, as your identical parent statements indicate, then would mean that it is attached to the egress qdisc as well. That clearly makes no sense, since it's an ingress limit.

Also, I'm pretty sure htb is not a supported ingress qdisc. Can you paste a link to the documentation you were following?

Comment: Ah! I see! Thank you for informing me. I thought it worked the same way on uploads and downloads. Clearly i was mistaken. I originaly only had one qdisk root.

I dont know how ingresse qdisc works but clearly you have pointed me in the right direction!

Link to the page were i got my previous information (that one is to limit your own computer but i did not find anyone about limiting clients computers so i thought i could make use of this somehow):
http://www.iplocation.net/tools/traffic-control.php